# Microsoft graph: Resumable upload doesnt work if the file name contains Norwegian character(ø)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am using resumable file upload which works fine for files without Norwegian character in it. If the file name has Norwegian character in it the uploadSession is established and after that when I sent the content on the uploadUrl returned from upload session request the call fails and gives the following error.

```
{
  "error":"invalid_request",
  "error_description":"This access token is not valid on this endpoint."
}
```

However from the same file if I remove this character (ø) everything works fine.

This the sample url returned from the createUploadSession endpoint.

`https://<sharepoint_sitename>/sites/jnu/_api/v2.0/drives/b!uey_5Lpf8Eu0-5HlGvJvFga89s_hTxNAg9kSsTlOBqajRqOF3ec-Rp6uqtbLNt4w/items/016GMDDVAF3UIOU2YNWVE3TX24ZV44WN4K/uploadSession?guid=%274ce82b5c-ede4-4d1d-af0a-6ff3b33c10b7%27&path=%27%7etmp41_Decisions+-+Advania+sdfsldfasduftest%u00f8+a%27&overwrite=True&rename=False&tempauth=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJub25lIn0.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.MTl0bEZ6cldwUlZEVUkwcEphUkpnWDRVelNnWnFWQndlVEtpbG9ndlhLYz0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a regression introduced when the session URLs were updated to a new format - it should now be fixed!